# My "instant self answer" was deleted

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-answers, instant-self-answer

Short summary: I've created a question with the "Answer your own question" checkbox and answered it. The next day I started seeing people answering the supposedly already answered question and it turned out that my only answer to my own question was deleted by the moderator: [How to dynamically load a font under iOS. (for real)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048549/how-to-dynamically-load-a-font-under-ios-for-real/14048550#14048550)

I've flagged my deleted answer, and described the problem, but haven't received an answer.
Can this be looked into?

Long story: I've researched some topic (dynamic loading of fonts in iOS) and in my search stumbled upon 10-20 variation of this question on SO, all of which had no good answers (either "not what the user asked" workarounds or "cannot be done" answers). Later I've found a recent blog post containing a simple solution to the problem. I've started to use it to answer the found SO questions, but after the 4th answer I thought that such activity could be considered spammy and is also futile since that questions already had accepted answers and my answers would be invisible. So I've decided to create a single self-answered question instead of answering every existing question. But, as I've already said, my self-answer was deleted.

The answer consisted of a link to the (Instapaper creator's) blog post describing the solution, the self-contained full code sample, the list of features and advantages of the method and a couple of links to the Apple documentation.

Comment: Was your answer only a link to the blog? Then it's likely deleted as a link-only-answer which aren't encouraged. We like questions and their answers to be self-contained and not *require* visits to external sites. If it wasn't a link-only-answer, well.. I'll be as curious as you as to why it was deleted. =)

Comment: The answer consisted of a link to the blog post, the self-contained full code sample, the list of features and advantages of the method and a couple of links to the Apple documentation.

Comment: Would seem legit to me, yeah.

Comment: I think "but after the 4th answer I thought that such activity could be considered spammy" may have been the cause. If you answered several questions with that link, code and bullet points, there may have been raised an "identical answers" flag. In that case, I wouldn't be surprised by the deletion. Are the other answers where you used that still in place?

Comment: @DanielFischer Hmmm. Well, I was slightly improving the answers as I posted them (I only added the documentation links and the bullet points to the self-answer.) The next day I've seen 2 deletions in my inbox: one answers to someone else's question and one own answer. Then all the mentions of deletions have disappeared. I looked in my profile right now and I cannot find any trace the existence of any of those answers or their deletion anywhere. My only lead is the link that I've posted which still shows the answer (to me).

Comment: I see it too (having 10K). And it is a bit more comprehensive than the other answer. It's not a great answer, since it doesn't contain much beyond the links and code, but I don't see anything that would make it delete-worthy on its own. So "identical answers" is the only reasonable explanation I can come up with now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You posted your self answer to your question verbatim on [another, much older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036362/ios-how-can-one-use-custom-fonts-in-uiwebview/14048481#14048481) as well, which triggered an automatic system flag informing us of duplicate content. The moderator that handled the flag deleted your answer because the questions looked extremely close in nature, where duplicate content could complicate an eventual merge.

I've restored your answer on the question you asked and answered. In the future, instead of pasting the same answer verbatim in several places, flag the other question, let us know that you wrote what you think is a better canonical question and answer and then let us evaluate it. When choosing duplicates to close and merge, we prefer to keep the version with the most comprehensive information, which appears to be what you provided in this case.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about using flags to suggest a better question. I won't use it right now since I need to carefully review the iOS font questions and separate the "dynamic font loading" questions from the "custom font" and "font not working" ones.

Comment: @Ark-kun Thanks for taking the time to dig. When you do flag, feel free to link to this meta post for context.